# PHP + SQL Somar dois valores da mesma coluna

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma tabela assim:

[image]

E preciso somar o valor do id 1 com o valor do id 15, salvando em uma variável no PHP.

Já pesquisei um monte mas não consegui algo específico pra isso. Obrigado por qualquer ajuda!

OBS: Tenho tentando o seguinte mas está retornando 1, quando o certo é retornar 49,14:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(valor) FROM tb_valores WHERE id = ($id1) OR id = ($id15) ");

echo $linhasemuso = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se alguém está passando pelo mesmo problema, aqui está a resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(valor) AS conta FROM tb_valores WHERE id = 1 OR id = 15 ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
echo $sum = $row['conta'];
```

Answer (score 0):

A logica é meio simples, mas funciona, se você adaptar, dá pra fazer um gerador de querys e inserir novos Ids sempre que necessario:

```
$execute = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM tabela_assim WHERE id = '$Id1' OR Id = '$Id2'");

$soma_total = 0;

while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){

$soma = $line['valor'];

$soma_total = $soma + $soma_total;
}

?>
```

Comment: Infelizmente aqui não funcionou. Fiz assim:

$execute = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tb_valores WHERE id = '$id1' AND id = '$id15'");
$soma_total = 0;
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){
        $soma = $line['valor'];
 $soma_total = $soma + $soma_total;
}
echo $soma_total;
E mesmo assim não funciona...

Comment: Uma variável, no caso id, não pode ser simultaneamente igual a dois valores distintos. Creio que na realidade queira utilizar o operador lógico OR e não AND.

Comment: @anonimo É vdd, me equivoquei nessa parte

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é resposta que funciona, mas é um código muito grande, gostaria de reduzir. Alguém se habilita?